# Installing some software by brodcasting in a network on all computers ?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking

Need [HTcondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) to be installed on all computers in network Which is our own campus network for throughput computing, we need maximum nodes so we can do it in a better way. Mentioned network have many computers which are desktops, laptops some are connected to LAN and some connected through WLAN. There are 3 networks faculty, students, and senior students but for simplicity I am assuming its just single network. and they have different operating systems(Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu, Windows XP). So how we can somehow broadcast it in network and install on all computers or prompt a pop up to user for installation ? I have looked into Microsoft [Group Policy to install software remotely](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314934) but this article applies to only Windows 2000 and its not cross platform either. How can I do that on cross platform using Linux(Ubuntu) or Windows ? 

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are they in or domain? WDS (Windows Deployment Service), WMI or powershell scripting.  For ubuntu ssh connection could work.

Comment: are they in or domain ? what does that mean ?

Comment: @cybernard can you use simple words so i can understand ?

Comment: Do you know what an "Active Directory" is?  WMI is a scripting language you can use to remotely connect to another computer assuming you have a valid admin credentials on that PC.